# How I extract number from text in Google Data Studio?

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I tried this but it's still showing `null` as you can see in the screen. Please help to solve this.

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(X,"[0-9]*[0-9]")
```

[image: Extract number from text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved using the [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below which uses the [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487) function to extract the numbers and the [`CAST`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7280720) function to ensure that it's a *Number* field:

```
CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(Attività, "(\\d+)") AS NUMBER )
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/ea29119c-4db2-40ab-86fe-924e419f0b11) and GIF to elaborate:

[image]